# golang bigquery docs specify done operator but it generates a compile error

Tags: go, google-bigquery

So the docs [here](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#RowIterator) state specifically to use `iterator.Done`:

`Next loads the next row into dst. Its return value is iterator.Done if there are no more results. Once Next returns iterator.Done, all subsequent calls will return iterator.Done.`

However if I attempt to use Done it generates a compiler error. Indeed, Done is not defined on the RowIterator docs [here](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#RowIterator).

My code (almost identical to the docs):

```
    it, err := job.Read(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    for {
        var rec MyType
        err := it.Next(&rec)
        // the docs say to use Done, but it provides an error

        if err == it.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        rows = append(rows, rec)
    }
```

When I try to build it, I get:

`./test.go:94:15: it.Done undefined (type *"cloud.google.com/go/bigquery".RowIterator has no field or method Done)`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`iterator.Done` is a [variable](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/api/iterator#pkg-variables) defined in the iterator package. So replace `it.Done` with `iterator.Done`. This is shown in [this example](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#example-RowIterator.Next-Struct):

```golang
package main

import (
    "cloud.google.com/go/bigquery"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, "project-id")
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: Handle error.
    }
    q := client.Query("select name, num from t1")
    it, err := q.Read(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: Handle error.
    }
    for {
        var row []bigquery.Value
        err := it.Next(&row)
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            // TODO: Handle error.
        }
        fmt.Println(row)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Omortis: It is clear - See the prototypes - https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#Job.Read and https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/iterator

Answer (score 2):

You have confused between the iterator returned from the [`Job.Read`](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/bigquery#Job.Read) call i.e. the `RowIterator` and the generic Google API `iterator` in https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/iterator

You should check the return value from the latter i.e. `err == iterator.Done` to check if the the iteration is complete. The sample codes under the documentation has useful examples explained - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/master/bigquery